# print object.object with mustache

Tags: javascript, mustache

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
var html,
    templ = '<p>{{config.title}}</p>',
    data = {config: {title: 'some text'}};
html = Mustache.to_html(templ, data);
alert(html);
```

With the [Mustache library](http://www.moustachelibrary.com/)?
Or maybe with some other library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted of mustache use underscore.js:

```
_.templateSettings = { interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g };
var templateStructure = 'Hello {{ name }}!';
var template = _.template(templateStructure);
alert(template(yourObject));
```

Be careful: the data You put in Your template is unescaped.

There is one more think:

If Your templateStructure contains 'null' You will get an error.
To make it work do this:

```
var templateStructure = 'Hello {{ name }}! Did You know that "null" will provide an error?';
    templateStructure.replace(/null/g, 'NULL_REPLACEMENT');
var template = _.template(templateStructure);
var out = template(yourObject);
    out = template.replace(/NULL_REPLACEMENT/g, 'null');
alert(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use moustache contexts:

```
var html,
    templ = '<p>{{#config}}{{title}}{{/config}}</p>',
    data = {config: {title: 'some text'}};
html = Mustache.to_html(templ, data);
alert(html);
```

-> `'<p>some text</p>'`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js
Usage

A quick example how to use mustache.js:

```
var view = {
  title: "Joe",
  calc: function() {
    return 2 + 4;
  }
}

var template = "{{title}} spends {{calc}}";

var html = Mustache.to_html(template, view);
```

template is a simple string with mustache tags and view is a JavaScript object containing the data and any code to render the template.